# Extracting elements from within list elements

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12)
df2 <- data.frame(A=10:19, B=9:18, C=8:17)
df3 <- data.frame(A=100:109, B=80:89, C=20:29)
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Is it possible to extract all of the `A` columns and put them into a new dataframe? The resulting dataframe I'm hoping to get is:

```
df4 <- data.frame (df1=1:10, df2=10:19, df3=100:109)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, except for the column names. If the list is named as in

```
my_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
```

then indeed

```
data.frame(lapply(my_list, `[[`, "A"))
#    df1 df2 df3
# 1    1  10 100
# 2    2  11 101
# 3    3  12 102
# 4    4  13 103
# 5    5  14 104
# 6    6  15 105
# 7    7  16 106
# 8    8  17 107
# 9    9  18 108
# 10  10  19 109
```

Otherwise,

```
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
head(data.frame(lapply(my_list, `[[`, "A")), 2)
#   X1.10 X10.19 X100.109     
# 1     1     10      100
# 2     2     11      101
head(data.frame(lapply(my_list, `[`, "A")), 2)
#   A A.1 A.2
# 1 1  10 100
# 2 2  11 101
```

so that you may want to assign the column names manually.